# Creating table using TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to create a table in TikZ with

1. the first column right-aligned, and the texts in each cell on the same line
2. the rest of the columns center-aligned, and each has width of 1cm

My attempt is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(dict)[matrix of nodes,below=of game,
    nodes={align=center,text width=1cm},
    row 1/.style={anchor=south},
    column 1/.style={text width=2cm,align=right},
  ]{
    meaning & $b_1$ & $b_2$ & $b_3$ & $b_1b_2$ & $b_1b_3$ & $b_2b_3$ & $b_1b_2b_3$\\
    common list \\
    private list\\
  };
  \draw(dict-1-1.south west)--(dict-1-8.south east);
  \draw(dict-1-1.north east)--(dict-3-1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is not as desired, since the texts in cells `dict-2-1` and `dict-3-1` spread over two lines. Also, texts in column 1 is not right aligned, despite `column 1/.style` being specified after `node/.style`.

What should I do?

Comment: The order of the options in the `\matrix` doesn’t matter because here you only append to style `every node` and define style `column 1`. The order of usage matters (in the internals of the `\matrix` macro). Either way, you need to do `column 1/.style={nodes={text width=2cm,align=right}}`. What is the purpose of `row 1`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks! Your suggestion works. How about making it into an actual answer? `row 1` aligns the nodes by their bottom border, so that the horizontal line doesn't have a slope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Remarks

This is just [@Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel)'s comment converted to an answer.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(dict)[matrix of nodes,%below=of game,
        nodes={align=center,text width=1cm},
        row 1/.style={anchor=south},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=2cm,align=right}}
    ]{
        meaning & $b_1$ & $b_2$ & $b_3$ & $b_1b_2$ & $b_1b_3$ & $b_2b_3$ & $b_1b_2b_3$\\
        common list \\
        private list\\
    };
    \draw(dict-1-1.south west)--(dict-1-8.south east);
    \draw(dict-1-1.north east)--(dict-3-1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]